# Error when trying to enter psql using a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

In my postgres.dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:10

ENV POSTGRES_USERNAME postgrestest
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD 123456
ENV POSTGRES_DB dbtest

EXPOSE 5432
```

I use docker build to create the image and then a docker run to create the container

I use `docker exec -it <container_name> psql -U`

resonates the error `psql: FATAL: role "root" does not exist`

If use `docker exec -it <container_name> psql -U postgrestest` resonates the same error

Comment: Can you post your complete `docker run` command?

Comment: @prithjnath docker build -t postgres.dockerfile .

Comment: That's your `docker build` command. I was looking for your `docker run` command

Answer (score 0):

The postgres user is defined with the environment variable **`POSTGRES_USER`** and not **`POSTGRES_USERNAME`**.
Source: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

So your *Dockerfile* should be:

```
FROM postgres:10

ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgrestest
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
ENV POSTGRES_DB=dbtest

EXPOSE 5432
```

---

And if you want to effectively login smoothly without having to add anything, I would advise you to use the environments variables `PGUSER`and `PGDATABASE`.
<sub>*More on those here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html*</sub>

So with does I can do a smooth connection:

```
FROM postgres:10

ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgrestest
ENV PGUSER="$POSTGRES_USER"
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
ENV POSTGRES_DB=dbtest
ENV PGDATABASE="$POSTGRES_DB"

EXPOSE 5432
```

And then running it:

```
$ docker run --name psql -d $(docker build -q .)
a1a6ba06293b8f1e22a0d504b5368feb87595c5c4db7b0bafdb87279dc936a26
$ docker exec -ti psql psql
psql (10.15 (Debian 10.15-1.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.

dbtest=#
```

Comment: `ENV KEY value` without an `=` still sets `KEY=value`.  The `=` format lets you set multiple variables in the same `ENV` statement, but requires more escaping if the value includes spaces.  (See "Alternative syntax" in the link you include.)

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze I was fooled by my IDE intellisense, I guess